# SSE: convert __m128 and __m128i into two __m128d

Tags: c++, c, optimization, sse

Two related questions.

This is what my code needs to do with fairly large amount of data. It is done inside inner loops and the performance is important.

1. Convert and array of __int32 into doubles (or convert __m128i into two __m128d).
2. Convert and array of floats into doubles (or convert __m128 into two __m128d).

Basically, I need function with the following signatures:

```
void convert_int_to_double(__int32 const * input, double * output);
void convert_float_to_double(float const * input, double * output);
```

Input and output pointers are aligned and the number of elements is a multiple of 4. The main problem is how to quickly unpack __m128 into two __m128d.

Comment: Why, exactly? I mean, I don't see what advantage there is to pre-computing the double-version of ints and floats. Ultimately, the FPU will be slower loading doubles than floats or ints since there's more data being moved.

Comment: Why are you doing conversions inside inner loops?  Just convert all your data to `double` up front in linear time, use `double` exclusively inside nested loops (with no conversions needed), and convert to the result type after, again in linear time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intrinsics [_mm_cvtepi32_pd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhwkxa6t.aspx) and [_mm_cvtps_pd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x763ty.aspx) convert the values to double.

This should be the loop:

```
__m128i* base_addr = ...;
for( int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i )
{
    __m128i epi32 = _mm_load_si128( base_addr + i );
    __m128d v0 = _mm_cvtepi32_pd( epi32 );
    epi32 = _mm_srli_si128( epi32, 8 );
    __m128d v1 = _mm_cvtepi32_pd( epi32 );
    ....
}
```

Comment: The link to _mm_cvtps_pd is broken, should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x763ty.aspx

Comment: I presume shifting by 8 bit will work even with __m128 after proper casting.

Comment: _mm_srli_si128 shifts by bytes not bits, and yes, it shifts all register types.